# Schedule Nuxt Static Site Generation and deploy on Azure

Tags: azure, nuxt3, azure-static-web-app

I'm using Nuxt3 to host my site.
I want it to have a serverless architecture, that a schedule build for the static site generation, and deploy it on Azure Static Webapps/ Azure Storage.

In short, I'm looking for a way that the static site generation of nuxt3 and deployment to Azure blob storage/ static web app **all happened on cloud, with a scheduler.**

However, I'm not using Azure pipeline or Github for this project, is there a way to achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: could you please share the code what u tried

Comment: @Sampath, just a fresh start nuxt3 project

Comment: Do you have any restriction for using GitHub Actions?

Comment: If not GitHub you can use Azure Functions.

Comment: refer to this git for the next Static Site Generation and deploy on [Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/deploy-nuxtjs)

Answer (score 0):

Deploy Static web app to Azure [Developer Center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/javascript/how-to/with-authentication/static-web-app-with-api/deploy-static-web-app-to-azure)

According to the above, there are only ways

- Git commit changes
- Azure DevOps
- Function API environment variables

AFIK, we can not create nextjs app in azure . but we can we can create  and Deploy  it  azure Static web app

- `npm install nuxt`  and
- Create a new app with  `npm init nuxt-app our app name`
- Deploy Nuxt sites with universal rendering on Azure Static [Web Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/deploy-nuxtjs) .
- `npm run dev -- -o`

**In local:**

[image]

- Add a README file  and git pull so it genereates yml file
- create a  Static web app with `git _App location_` is  `/` `_Api location_` is  ``` .output/server`` _Output location_ ```  is `.output/public`.
- Use the Reference [staticwebdev/nuxt-3-starter](https://github.com/staticwebdev/nuxt-3-starter)
- Click on Browse

[image]

- Refer to this Upload image to Blob Storage JavaScript on [Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/javascript/tutorial/browser-file-upload-azure-storage-blob?tabs=github-codespaces) .